# How to concatenate string and integer values in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to concatenate string and integer values in JMeter as below

```
for(int i in 1..100){
    def cloudItemId="cloudItemId"+i;
    def deviceItemId="deviceItemId"+i;
}
```

but I'm getting this below error

```
Response message:Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
java.lang.String.positive() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: notify(), size(), tokenize()
```

How can Iconcatenate with cloudItemId/deviceItemId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `+` sign is used for mathematic plus in integers and concatenation in Strings

You can concatenate using `<<`:

```
for(int i in 1..100){    
    def cloudItemId="cloudItemId" <<i;
    log.info(cloudItemId.toString());
    def deviceItemId="deviceItemId"<<i;
    log.info(cloudItemId.toString());
}
```

Or call `String.valueOf` to concat Strings:

```
for(int i in 1..100){
    def cloudItemId="cloudItemId" + String.valueOf(i);
    log.info(cloudItemId);
    def deviceItemId="deviceItemId"+ String.valueOf(i)
    log.info(cloudItemId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest JMeter 5.4.1 (you're [supposed to be using the latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) just in case):

[image]

so pay attention to your syntax and suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

You can also slightly refactor your code to use [GStrings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes) and make it more [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black):

```
1.upto(100, { i ->
    def cloudItemId = "cloudItemId$i"
    def deviceItemId = "deviceItemId$i"
    log.info('cloudItemId: ' + cloudItemId)
})
```

[image]